# Configuring a thread pool for Spring Boot asynchronous TaskExecutors?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/07/understanding-callable-and-spring-deferredresult.html) which explains the difference between using a `Callable` and a `DeferredResult` with the servlet 3.0 spec and Spring.  For `Callable`s spring manages the thread, so I presume then that we need to configure a thread pool?  How is this configured for Spring Boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebMvcConfigurationSupport.configureAsyncSupport()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#configureAsyncSupport-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer-) is used to set up async request processing. [AsyncSupportConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/AsyncSupportConfigurer.html) provides configuration for all controller methods returning `Callable` and `DeferredResult`. The underlying thread pool can be configured through [AsyncSupportConfigurer.setTaskExecutor()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/AsyncSupportConfigurer.html#setTaskExecutor-org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor-) using appropriate `AsyncTaskExecutor` implementation (`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for example). It's also possible to update this configuration on per-request basis by returning `WebAsyncTask` instead for `Callable`. Linked javadocs describe all of it in more detail.